# Installing ripple coin daemon and Ripple coin-QT in ubuntu gives error

Tags: bitcoind, ripple, ubuntu, daemon, compiling

I install ripple coin from Github as I did for other coins. On cloning rippled [rippled](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/) from Github, I can't find files under rippled as I found for other coins. I can not find much information regarding installing about ripplecoind.

```
~/rippled$ ls
bin  Builds  doc  LICENSE  package.json  README.md  SConstruct  site_scons  src  test
```

I followed the following steps:

```
$git clone https://github.com/ripple/rippled.git
$cd ripplecoind/src
$make -f makefile.unix
make: makefile.unix: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `makefile.unix'.  Stop.
```

Can anybody help me with installation steps?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing Ripplecoin, which [appears to be a defunct altcoin](https://github.com/1033326265/litecoin), with the [Ripple network](https://ripple.com/), which is another beast entirely.